# wp_nav_menu not working correctly in my underscores theme

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, javascript

I'm using a theme based on underscores, and I have registered my menus in the following way.

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary' ),
        'social_media' => esc_html__( 'Social Media' ),
    ) );
};
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

When calling the menus like so:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    ['theme_location' => 'primary']
);

wp_nav_menu(
    ['theme_location' => 'social_media']
);
```

only the primary menu shows up.

I checked if themenu exists and is registered with `has_nav_menu()` and it returns `true`.

Here is my backend. The menu is registered and assigned to a location:

[image]

**No, it's not on display none. I checked the markup, and it's empty.**

I disabled JS and it's still the same.
I tried adding a new menu:

```
…
    'secondary' => esc_html__( 'Secondary' ),
…
```

and went through all the procedure, and when calling

```
wp_nav_menu(
    ['theme_location' => 'secondary']
);
```

nothing happens. Markup is still empty. Somehow it's only working with the name `'primary'`

Comment: Can you please confirm if you have registered `secondary` menu?

Comment: "The menu is registered and assigned to a location" - you do have menu *items* in the "Social Media" menu? Do you have custom functions/code which may be filtering items in that menu (location)?

Answer (score 1):

If found out that this is removing my menu:

```
function add_menu_icon ( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $elements = '<li class="custom-logo">'
                    .   get_custom_logo()   .
                    '</li>';
                    $elements .= $items;
        $items = $elements;
        return $items;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_menu_icon', 10, 2 );
```

I still haven't figured out why.

Comment: You need to *always* return the `$items`. So move the `return $items;` to outside the `if` block: `if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) { ... } return $items; // <- here`